# Finding duplicates, and uniques of the duplicates in a csv

Tags: python, linux, bash, csv, awk

I'm needing to create a script, that will load a csv (sometimes tagged as .inf) to memory, and evaluate the data for a type of duplicate. The csv itself will always have different information in every field, but the columns will be the same. Around 100~ columns. In my examples, i'm going to narrow it to 10 columns for readability.

The "type" of duplicate i'm looking for is a bit odd. I need to first find all duplicates in column 2. Then i need to look at that set of duplicates, and look at column 8 (In my actual csv, it will be column 84). 
Looking at column 8 i need to only output data that is:

A. Duplicate in column 2

B. Unique in column 8

There may only be 2 duplicates from column 2, and their column 8 is the same. I don't need to see that. If there are 3 duplicates from column 2, and their column 8, 2 are the same, and 1 is unique, i need to see all 3 FULL rows.

```
Desired input
m,123veh,john;doe,10/1/2019,ryzen,split,32929,38757ace,turn,left
m,123veh,john;doe,10/1/2019,ryzen,split,32929,495842,turn,left
m,837iec,john;doe,10/1/2019,ryzen,split,32929,12345,turn,left
m,837iec,john;doe,10/1/2019,ryzen,split,32929,12345,turn,left
m,382ork,john;doe,10/1/2019,ryzen,split,32929,38757,turn,left
m,382ork,john;doe,10/1/2019,ryzen,split,32929,38757,turn,left
m,382ork,john;doe,10/1/2019,ryzen,split,32929,4978d87,turn,left
```

This data is constantly going to be different, and even the number of characters in column 8 may vary.

```
Desired output
m,123veh,john;doe,10/1/2019,ryzen,split,32929,38757ace,turn,left
m,123veh,john;doe,10/1/2019,ryzen,split,32929,495842,turn,left
m,382ork,john;doe,10/1/2019,ryzen,split,32929,38757,turn,left
m,382ork,john;doe,10/1/2019,ryzen,split,32929,38757,turn,left
m,382ork,john;doe,10/1/2019,ryzen,split,32929,4978d87,turn,left
```

You can see from my desired output, i don't need to see the rows with 837iec because, while their column 2 is duplicate, both the columns 8 match each other. I don't need to see that. While for something like 382ork, 2 of the column 8s match, one is unique. I need to see all 3.

I'll be using this on unix systems, and my desired way of using it would be to type "./scriptname filename.csv" and the output can either be standard output, or into a log file if needed.

I haven't been able to find a way to do this as how i'm needing to compare column 8 is confusing me. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

I had found this in another thread that at least gets me the full rows, of the duplicates of column 2. Thought i don't fully understand how its working.

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f
{
    lines[$1][NR] = $0;
}
END {
    for (vehid in lines) {
        if (length(lines[vehid]) > 1) {
            for (lineno in lines[vehid]) {
                # Print duplicate line for decision purposes
                print lines[vehid][lineno];
                # Alternative: print line number and line
                #print lineno, lines[vehid][lineno];
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The issue i have is it doesn't take the next column into consideration. It also does not handle blank columns well. My csv will have 100~ columns, and 50~ of them might be entirely blank.

Comment: when you say "entirely blank", you mean they will be "empty"? like `data1,data2,,,,,data8,....` (I hope?) Good luck.

Comment: Yes, sorry. Empty is correct, just as your example there.

Comment: Bye the way, good show on your improved Q and you're getting "eyes" on your problem right away! Good luck.

Comment: AND if you're just getting into this sort of processing and expect to be doing it a lot more (and have some control over your data sources), Consider switching to tab-separated data or `|` separators. Using a char that isn't (or can't) appear in your data elimiates a whole class of problem when you do need a comma to be in your data ;-) . Good luck!

Comment: @shellter, Indeed very Good first question T_Wrong, keep it up, cheers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Could you please try following.

```
awk '
BEGIN{
  FS=","
}
FNR==NR{
  a[$2]++
  b[$2,$8]++
  c[$2]=(c[$2]?c[$2] ORS:"")$0
  next
}
a[$2]>1 && b[$2,$8]==1{
  print c[$2]
  delete a[$2]
}' <(sort -t',' -k2 Input_file) <(sort -t',' -k2 Input_file)
```

With your shown example output is as follows.

```
m,123veh,john;doe,10/1/2019,ryzen,split,32929,38757ace,turn,left
m,123veh,john;doe,10/1/2019,ryzen,split,32929,495842,turn,left
m,382ork,john;doe,10/1/2019,ryzen,split,32929,38757,turn,left
m,382ork,john;doe,10/1/2019,ryzen,split,32929,38757,turn,left
m,382ork,john;doe,10/1/2019,ryzen,split,32929,4978d87,turn,left
```

***Explanation:*** Adding detailed explanation for above code.

```
awk '                                                     ##Starting awk program from here.
BEGIN{                                                    ##Starting BEGIN section from here.
  FS=","                                                  ##Setting FS as comma here.
}                                                         ##Closing BEGIN section here.
FNR==NR{                                                  ##Checking condition FNR==NR which will be TRUE when first time Input_file is being read.
  a[$2]++                                                 ##Creating an array named a whose index is $2 and increment its value with 1 each time it comes here.
  b[$2,$8]++                                              ##Creating an array named b whose index is $2,$8 and increment its value with 1 each time it comes here.
  c[$2]=(c[$2]?c[$2] ORS:"")$0                            ##Creating an array named c whose index is $2 and value will be keep concatenating its same indexs whole line value.
  next                                                    ##next will skip all further statements from here.
}                                                         ##Closing BLOCK for FNR==NR condition here.
a[$2]>1 && b[$2,$8]==1{                                   ##Checking condition if array a with index $2 value is greater than 1 AND array b with index $2,$8 value is 1.
  print c[$2]                                             ##Then print array c value with $2 here.
  delete a[$2]                                            ##Deleting array a value with $2 here which will make sure NO DUPLICATE lines are getting printed.
}' <(sort -t',' -k2 file) <(sort -t',' -k2 file)          ##Sending Input_files in sorted format from 2nd field to make sure all values are coming together before doing operations on it.
```

Comment: This looks like its doing the trick! Thank you so much! I've been struggling with this for a while now.

Comment: @T_Wrong, glad that it helped you, your welcome. I have also added a detailed explanation(took some mins to add detailed one :) ) any queries are most welcome, cheers.

Comment: The detailed explanation is very helpful, thank you.

Answer (score 2):

A Python solution to this problem could be (here I used `_id` and `qty` for the 2 captured fields):

```
import csv
from collections import defaultdict

f = open('f1.txt', 'r')
d = defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(list))

csv_reader = csv.reader(f)

for row in csv_reader:
    _id = row[1]
    qty = row[7]
    d[_id][qty].append(row)

f.close()

for _id in d:
    for qty in d[_id]:
        # if there are more than 1 'qty'
        # OR there is only 1 'qty' and there is only 1 line in the values
        # for the array (row) (allows a record with only 1 line)
        if len(d[_id]) > 1 or len(d[_id][qty]) == 1:
            for row in d[_id][qty]:
                print(','.join(row))
```

Prints:

```
m,123veh,john;doe,10/1/2019,ryzen,split,32929,38757ace,turn,left
m,123veh,john;doe,10/1/2019,ryzen,split,32929,495842,turn,left
m,382ork,john;doe,10/1/2019,ryzen,split,32929,38757,turn,left
m,382ork,john;doe,10/1/2019,ryzen,split,32929,38757,turn,left
m,382ork,john;doe,10/1/2019,ryzen,split,32929,4978d87,turn,left
```

Comment: Thanks! I have been exploring a bit more Python, so this is helpful.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with pandas, if you can use that:

```
import pandas as pd
e = pd.read_csv('out16.txt', header=None)
e.columns = list(range(1,11))
e.drop_duplicates(subset=[2,8]).set_index(1).to_csv('out_test.txt', header=False)
```

```
e = e.drop_duplicates(subset=[2,8]).set_index(1)
e
```

output:

```
       2         3          4      5      6      7        8     9     10
1        
m  123veh  john;doe  10/1/2019  ryzen  split  32929  38757ace turn  left                                                               
m  123veh  john;doe  10/1/2019  ryzen  split  32929   495842  turn  left
m  837iec  john;doe  10/1/2019  ryzen  split  32929    12345  turn  left
m  382ork  john;doe  10/1/2019  ryzen  split  32929    38757  turn  left
m  382ork  john;doe  10/1/2019  ryzen  split  32929  4978d87  turn  left
```

Comment: This is the first i'm hearing about pandas, but i'm certainly going to look into it!

Comment: @T_Wrong Pandas is awesome, definitely recommend it!